# connection between server running perl skript and android

Tags: android, perl, sockets

I am trying to send data from my Android phone to my home-server by using sockets. My server runs Linux so I used Perl to code the script for my server. The connection works fine and I can send data to my client running on the phone.

Problem is, when I send something (first try was a simple string) to the server, I don't receive anything at the servers side. Everything works fine if I use telnet to send a string to the server.

I am sitting here for some time now and I looked if there was a similar question to mine and could not find any in which the problem is discussed for Android to Perl-script. Here is my code for the Android app:

```
  try {
    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.178.22", 22222);
    Statusinformation("connection with server succeed");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    Statusinformation(input.readLine());

    OutputStream outstream =socket.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstream);
    out.println("This is a test message from client on phone!\n");
    socket.close();

  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Statusinformation("connection unsucsessfull");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

on my phone I receive this if i execute the above code:

connection with server succeed!
[image]

and on the server side I'm using this code to receive the string from socket clients:

```
use IO::Socket;

my $server = IO::Socket::INET -> new(
  Proto     => 'tcp',
  LocalPort => 22222,
  Listen    => SOMAXCONN,
);

print "Server started..\n";

while (1) {
  next unless my $conect = $server -> accept();
  my $childconection = fork;
  if ($childconection == 0) {
    handle_connection($conect);
  }
}

sub handle_connection
{
  my $sock = shift;
  my $client_message="";
  my $client_addr = $sock -> peerhost;

  print "connection: $client_addr connected\n";
  print $sock "hi $client_addr, you are connected!\n";

  while (1) {
    open (Tempfile, '>>tempfile.txt');

    while ($client_message = <$sock>) {
      print Tempfile $client_message;
      print $client_message;
    }

    close (Tempfile);
  }
  close($sock);
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: How do you create your socket on the server side? Can you show us the relevant code? Also, I think that `While` should be lowercase.

Comment: ok I updated almost the entire code for the server. while was uppercase because i entered the sample manually (sry). if there is another mistake like that then just ignore it if it isn't really a logical one.

Comment: Well, it works for me: The Perl script receives and prints out requests. However, the child processes go into an infinite loop when the socket has no further data. What is your rationale for the `while (1)` loop in the child?

Comment: the while (1) whitin the sub handle_connection is nedded in order to not limit the data the client wants to send. the moment the client closes the connection, the loop is left and the thread closed. This works fine if i use a client(written in perl) that does the exact same thing as the client in the android code above. or if i use telnet. It just won't work with the client written in android and I don't get why since the connection is established and I receive prints from the server. I only can't receive some at the servers side or maybe i proyess the prints wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

ok now I am a little ashamed.
I solved the problem by adding:
out.flush();
the flush() method assures that all pending data is send to the target and flushs the target.